# Sinon stub.returns() not returning correct value

Tags: sinon

Sinon stub.returns() method does not return the correct response according the documentation.  Any ideas why?

```
stubThis = sinon.stub().returns('123');

console.log(stubThis); // returns stub, but expect it to return 123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke `stubThis`: `console.log(stubThis());`

When you call `sinon.stub()` you get back a function that returns `undefined`:

```
var stub = sinon.stub();
stub() // return undefined
```

When you invoke the `.returns` method on that function you specify its return value and get back the original function:

```
stub.returns('123') === stub; // true
stub() // now returns '123'
```

So in your code above `stubThis` is not supposed to be `'123'`. It is a function whose return value is `'123'`. You just need to invoke `stubThis`:

```
console.log(stubThis()); // logs '123'
```